# Como deshabilitar un formulario dependiendo del usuario que inicie sesion

Tags: php

en el tipo usuario solo pude haber dos que son ADMINISTRADOR y USUARIO. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se ingrese al sistema si el ADMINISTRADOR ingresa los campos se encontraran los campos habilitados es por php.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ehhh... con un 'if'

Comment: Juega con el atributo [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) o readonly. Si en la variable de sesión el usuario es admin entonces `$disabled='';` de lo contrario `$disabled='disabled';`. Luego imprimes esa variable dentro de los inputs que necesites "bloquear".

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].